# Difference between "measure" and "metric"

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

I was reading about [mathematical structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure) and came across the distinction of metric and measure as follows:

```
A measure: intervals along the real line have a specific length, which can be extended to the Lebesgue measure on many of its subsets.
A metric: there is a notion of distance between points.
```

Question: Isn't metric a super category of measure? So a measure is a form of a metric?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a measure is not a kind of metric.

In the contexts you quote, a measure tells you the *size* of a set. A metric tells you the *distance* between two points.

Comment: noted. but isnt measure quantify the extent of something, so in a way a distance is extent of closeness of one object to another?

Comment: Terminology in mathematics, such as a "measure", has precisely defined meanings, distinct from the meaning these words may have in everyday language. Of course, in the sense of everyday English, a metric does measure something, namely the distance of two points, but "a measure" in a mathematical context is a different thing.

Comment: @Thorgott noted. So essentially measure theory pertains to measure on sets, right?

Comment: Yes. More precisely, we have an ambient space we are working in (which is a set) and what we measure are certain subsets of that space.

Comment: @Thorgott makes so much sense!